# Jquery- Dialog missing title bar close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I've seen quite a few topics here about that matter, but none of them helped me sadly :(
In my case, it's not only the "x" that's missing but the whole button and I don't know why nor how to fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

And this is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="ZF_dialog" title="Zusatzfelder" style="display:none;" ><br><br>
<table id="table_zf" style="width:100%; border-style:ridge; border-radius:8px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style= 'width:10%'>Name</th>
                    <th style= 'width:10%'>Typ </th>
                    <th style= 'width:10%'>Wert</th>
                    <th style= 'width:10%'>Optionen</th>
                    <th style= 'width:10%'>Pflicht</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Java Script:

```
$(this).find('i').off('click').on('click',function(){
    console.log(that.attr("value"));
    console.log("jeah");
 $( "#ZF_dialog" ).dialog({
    draggable: true,
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 250},
    height: 320,
    width: 500,
    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+250' }
});
let temp = $("<tr><td id='USER"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"'>"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"</td><td id='USERa"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"'>"+GlobalVarUS[key]["projektname"]+"</td><td id='USERb"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"'>"+GlobalVarUS[key]["aktiv"]+"</td><td id='USERc"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"'>"+GlobalVarUS[key]["verrechenbar"]+"</td><td id='ZFDialog"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS[key]["pk_pr_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-list' aria-hidden='true' style= 'cursor:pointer'></i></td></tr>");
temp.appendTo("#table_zf");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample HTML markup:

```
    <div id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog">
      <table border="1">
            <tr><td>S.no</td><td>Text</td></tr>
            <tr><td>One</td><td>Text</td></tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

jQuery dialog code :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();
});
```

My code run using cdn path for plugin

Use miss the image the ui-icons_777777_256x240.png or path is not correct.